# AHK copy browser text without activating window

Tags: web-scraping, autohotkey

So one way I can do this is for example.

```
MouseMove, %xpos%, %ypox% (inside browser)
MouseClick, %xpos%, %ypox%
Send ^a
Send ^c
text := Clipboard
msgbox %text%
```

But I want to get the text without clicking at all! Like UrlDownloadToVar but instead of returning the html I want the text. It has to return the text because the website I am working on is protected and in java and doesn't return proper information by copying the source-code.

Comment: Try [ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm).

Comment: Thanks buddy. This is a good place to start for anyone else interested.